# when cancel photo a ghost file is created cannot delete

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

I created an app that allows you to save a photo with a specific name, the process is: 1-You write the name 2-You write the type of operation 3-You press take picture 4-All the info in 1&2 is put into the name and it takes you to the camera.

When you take the picture everything works fine, but if you close the camera instead of taking the photograph a ghost file is created, with a size of 0 bytes, and when you open it with the gallery, it says file does not exist.

```
 int imgNbr = 0;
values = new ContentValues();
do{
    file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + containerId.getText().toString() + "_" + dateInfo + "_" + eventType + "_" + imgNbr + ".png");
    Log.d("TAG", Integer.toString(imgNbr));
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + containerId.getText().toString() + "_" + dateInfo + "_" + eventType + "_" + imgNbr + ".png");
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, containerId.getText().toString() + "_" + dateInfo + "_" + eventType + "_" + imgNbr+ ".png");
    imgNbr++;
}
while(file.exists());

Log.d("TAG", "OUT OF WHILE WITH VALUE" + Integer.toString(imgNbr-1));

imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICTURE_RESULT);
```

I tried to delete it manually on activity result but it does not work, all the logs return false

```
@Override @Nullable
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICTURE_RESULT){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Imagen guardada correctamente",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED && requestCode == PICTURE_RESULT){
        //file.delete();

        Log.d("TAG", "file.isFile()" + file.isFile());
        Log.d("TAG", "file.canRead()" + file.canRead());
        Log.d("TAG", "file.delete()" + file.delete());}}
```

Comment: `imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);`. You do not even have to call the following camera intent. You already created tge gost file here.

Comment: Further younever use that file object.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain a bit further? 1- If I dont call the camera intent how can I open the camera?  2-Where did I create the ghost file? Is it when I assign the imageUri? I use the object in the intent.putExtra

Comment: Mygod..you created the gost file wirh the line i quoted.

Comment: Ok, I understand, how am I supposed to pass this "name" information to the intent, if I dont create the imageUri?

Comment: Cant you do it afterwards? After the image has been taken and saved? In onActivityResult() ?

Comment: You mean renaming the file afterwards without modifying the parameters when I call the intent? That could be an option, can I retrieve the file name in onActivityResult?

Comment: No not renaming. Just adding info. You yourself are determining filename, fullpath and fileuri before you create the intent. You know all. So you can all use in onActivityResult() yourself too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept working on the code and this approach worked correctly, without creating ghost images upon cancellation.

```
            int imgNbr = 0;
            do{
                file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/fotosHH/" + containerId.getText().toString() + "_" + dateInfo + "_" + eventType + "_" + imgNbr + ".png");
                imgNbr++;
            }
            while(file.exists());

            String imageFolderPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/fotosHH";
            imgNbr--;
            String imageName = containerId.getText().toString() + "_" + dateInfo + "_" + eventType + "_" + imgNbr + ".png";
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(new File(imageFolderPath, imageName)));
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICTURE_RESULT);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should delete the file if the picture has been rejected, something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

     /**** TAKING PICTURE USING CAMERA****/
     if(requestCode == PICTURE_RESULT && resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        if(imageUri!=null){ // GLOBAL variable in your activity
           File f = new File(imageUri.getPath());
           f.delete();
        }
     }
     else if (requestCode == PICTURE_RESULT && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
           // do your work
     }
}
```

Comment: I did this and the return value for f.delete() is false. The black picture remains in the gallery

Comment: @RodrigoMiranda Change `imageUri = getContentResolver()...` to `file.createNewFile(); imageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);`

Comment: The application crashes when I do the mentioned modification, so I added         StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build()); in the onCreate, and by doing so the app does not store any picture at all

Comment: @RodrigoMiranda IS your Android API>22?